# GDPR: can vendors accept core dumps or logs

Tags: gdpr

As a software vendor, am I allowed to accept core dumps or application logs from my customers to investigate a crash or malfunction even though they most likely contain personally identifiable information that may be subject to GDPR law?

It sounds like the rule of thumb "Do not keep personal information longer than necessary" covers this: the dump/logs are essential to help resolve a critical problem, and I would of course delete the dump and any logs sent to me as soon as I've found a solution.

However, since I am a software vendor external to the company the data was entrusted to, I am not so sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It depends.

The GDPR doesn't prohibit the processing of personal data.

In your scenario you are the "processor" and your customer is the "controller".

> ‘controller’ means the natural or legal person, public authority,
>   agency or other body which, alone or jointly with others, determines
>   the purposes and means of the processing of personal data; where the
>   purposes and means of such processing are determined by Union or
>   Member State law, the controller or the specific criteria for its
>   nomination may be provided for by Union or Member State law;
>
> ‘processor’ means a natural or legal person, public authority, agency
>   or other body which processes personal data on behalf of the
>   controller;

They can be the same entity but note that the obligations of the controller and processor differ. The obligations specific to the processor are given in Article 28, including what a contract between the controller and processor must say. Pay attention to section 10 to prevent you/your company from being considered to be a controller.

To mitigate risk, you and your customer might prefer the data to be anonymised before it is sent to you. Indeed anonymisation is obligatory if the job can be done without personal data. And if the data is anonymised then it won't engage GDPR. But if anonymised data prevents such an investigation, it doesn't necessarily mean you may not accept personal data, it 'just' means that you must process the data in compliance with GDPR.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into how I can avoid coredumps holding any private information :)

Answer (score 1):

### If you comply with GDPR, yes

However, if you are asking this question it seems that you have not taken the steps you need to take in order to comply.

Comment: Thanks. Let's say I'm asking on behalf of the employer :). They're very strict in their GDPR compliancy, but they're very antsy about this particular thing and won't accept any logs or core dumps which makes it near impossible for us to debug customer's issues. Is there a bit of legal code that explicitly allows this kind of usage?